# How do I use {polished} package with {brochure} framework?

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, shinyapps, golem

This was a complicating in logic execution i came across using `{polished}` and `{brochure}`.
When placing `secure_ui`/`secure_server` inside of a `brochure::Page()` in the same order of the example given by the `{polished}` dev team, there are changes to how a Shiny App is deploy on the `{brochure}` infrastructure. I was not sure where to relocate the polsiehd logic to.

**Differences**

- no global.R file in a `brochureApp()`
- multiple calls to different module_ui/server functions since each `brochure::page()` is its owns shiny session
- single page shinyApp vs true multipage shinyApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When needing to merge the two logics you must:

1. move `polished_config()` in `globals.R` --> `golem::runApp()` [initiate global setting for `brochureApp()`]

```
run_app <- function(
  onStart = NULL,
  options = list(),
  enableBookmarking = NULL,
  ...
) {

  # old 'globals.R' logic 
  polished_config(
    app_name = "humblFinance",
    api_key = "xxxx"
  )

  with_golem_options(
    app = brochureApp(
      # Putting the resources here
      golem_add_external_resources(),
      page1(),
    ),
    golem_opts = list(...)
  )
}
```

2. wrap each `brochure::page() ui/server with` polished::secure_ui/server()`

```
# an example login page
login <- function(id = "login", href = "/login") {


  page(
    href = href,
    ui = secure_ui(
      mod_login_ui(id = id),
      sign_in_page_ui = sign_in_custom()
      ),
    server = secure_server(
      function(input, output, session) {
      mod_login_server(id = id)
      }
    )
  )
}
```

*NOTE*

`sign_in_custom()` is a function that returns a customized UI object from `polished::sign_in_default()` to create personal business webpages.
I would recommend wrapping `polished::sign_in_default()` in a custom global function since you will need to define this on ever `brochure::page()` that you want to have protected behind `polished` auth.

once you authenticate one page through polished, you will be able to access all other protected pages while you are still logged in. After loggign out and attempting to access any one of the protected pages will result in a custom login page